# How to circumvent no static property inheritance in OOP?

Tags: oop

So I have a whole bunch of classes inheriting a base class. Each class need to have their own array of some values, basically a static array since I don't need one for each instance. But since static variables can't be inherited, I would have to declare this static array for every single class, and override the methods operating on the array (even if the method is always the same). The only solution I can think if is to use non-static arrays, but then I will have an extra array for each instance. Is there any way to get around? To only have 1 array for each class, and not declaring multiple of the same method?

Comment: static variables can't be inherited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would have to declare this static array for every single class

Well, you kind of have to do that anyway.  Since each one needs its own version of the array.

You don't want an instance array for obvious performance reasons, that makes sense.  But how about an instance *method* to access the array?  Something like this:

```
abstract class Widget
    static array MyValues = [1,2,3]

    abstract array GetValues
        return MyValues

    void DoSomething
        // reference GetValues instead of MyValues
```

Then in overriding classes:

```
class SpecificWidget inherits Widget
    static array MySpecificValues = [2,3,4]

    override array GetValues
        return MySpecificValues
```

The mechanics might change slightly depending on the language being used, but the overall idea should work.  Each type defines an instance method which can be overridden, the sole purpose of which is to act as a kind of factory for accessing the values.

Once abstracted like this, those values can live basically anywhere.  In a static array, in an external cache somewhere, in a database, etc.  The rest of the code would couple to the abstraction, not to the storage of the values.

Comment: I guess it's the simplest way, it would be nice to say "every class has this array of length N" in the super class, but it also save some space that those who needs a smaller array has different size for the array.